# JS created html links won't open in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

`<a href='http://www.xyz.hu/xyz' alt='Kosár' title='Kosár'>Megtekintés</a>`

Also:
- A setinterval refreshes the sibling's content every sec, shouldnt matter for this element, i disabled it and still wont work.
- it has a css3 transition effect on it (when hovered)
- normal chrome and chrome canary won't open these links, still, it appears at the bottom, and right click is possible, middle + left click aren't working.
- works in every other browser.

edit 1:

Long code comes, becouse i have no idea what causes this.

http://pastebin.com/bSnTYAEG

link at line: 79 - 86

edit 2: Without the transitions it still doesnt work, mouseover function keeps refreshing its content when the mouse moves / does something on the main container. (imo it shouldnt do this)

+Not working in safari too.

Comment: can you show me more of your code

Comment: The question is not clear at all. Can you add more code please?

Comment: Here's a shot in the dark guess: The anchor element is being covered by another element on top of it and thus, won't let you click the anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed mouseover to **mouseenter**, working now. I really should've read the JQuery event docs.